# How to group over lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [['a','b','c'], ['a','d'], ['c','c']]})`

And I want to group the dataframe so it will look like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']], 'count': [[2],[1],[3],[4]]})
```

If I use the `pd.groupby('col1').count()` option in python I get the error

> "Unhashable type: 'list'.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need flatten lists by DataFrame constructor, create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].values.tolist()).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['col1','count']
df1 = df1.sort_values('col1')
print (df1)
  col1  count
1    a      2
2    b      1
0    c      3
3    d      1
```

And if really want lists (some pandas function can failed) add [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df1 = df1.applymap(lambda x: [x])
print (df1)
  col1 count
1  [a]   [2]
2  [b]   [1]
0  [c]   [3]
3  [d]   [1]
```

Another solution with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) + [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
from collections import Counter

df1 = pd.Series(Counter(np.concatenate(df['col1']))).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['col1','count']
df1 = df1.applymap(lambda x: [x])
print (df1)
  col1 count
0  [a]   [2]
1  [b]   [1]
2  [c]   [3]
3  [d]   [1]
```